# How to make sender to be a Button and not the MainWindow in WPF CommandBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

The Button in WPF MainWindow has normal command attribute. When clicked the handler method receives sender. But the sender is always MainWidow. How to get sender to be a Button ? I need it to be a particular button, because I set this command to several buttons and want to use single handler for many senders. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the OriginalSource on the event arguments, it should hold the sender who invoked the command!

Hope this helps!